# Jest: How to mock angular percentage pipe inside custom pipe?

Tags: angular, jestjs

pipe.ts:

```
import { PercentPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'conversion' })
export class ConversionPipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private readonly percentPipe: PercentPipe) {}

transform(value: number, info?: string): string {
if (!value) {
  return '';
}

return this.percentPipe.transform(value, info); 

}
```

pipe.spec.ts:

```
import { PercentPipe } from '@angular/common'; 
import { LOCALE_ID }
from '@angular/core'; 
import { MockBuilder, MockRender } from
'ng-mocks'; 
import { ConversionPipe } from './conversion.pipe';

describe('ConversionPipe', () => {
   beforeEach(() =>
     MockBuilder(PercentPipe)
   );

   it('Add given digit count after the decimal point in final percentage value', () => {
     const fixture = MockRender(
       '{{ value | conversion : info }}',
       {
          value: 0.00431,
          info: '1.0-2'
       }
    ).nativeElement as HTMLElement;
   expect(fixture.innerHTML).toBe('+4.3%');
   });
});
```

it is throwing an error " ASSERTION ERROR: Expected localeId to be

```
defined [Expected=> null != undefined <=Actual]"
```

Comment: Why would you mock it? You don't own it, treat its use as an implementation detail.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you explain in detail?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you solve it? @SathyapriyaPrabhakaran

Comment: @Alba no Alba I couldn’t